# Mongodb query optimization for where clause

Tags: mongodb-query, query-optimization

I am using MongoDB version 3.2.8. I am executing `db.Member.find({$where: "var d = new Date(this.Birthdate); return d.getUTCDate() === 4 && d.getUTCMonth() === 2 && d.getUTCFullYear() !== 2017" })` It is taking too much time to execute this query on my local mongo. Is there any alternative for this query so query can optimize?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the MongoDB [Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). I tested using the [Mingo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mingo) library for Javascript

Example:

```
var mingo = require('mingo')

var data = [{
  _id: 100,
  Birthdate: new Date("1995-02-04")
}]

var pipeline = [
    {
        $project: { M: { $month: "$Birthdate"}, Y: { $year: "$Birthdate"}, D: { $dayOfMonth: "$Birthdate"}, Birthdate: 1 }
    },
    {
        $match: { $and: [ { D: 4 }, { M: 2 }, {Y: { $ne: 2017 } } ] }
    },
    {
        $project: { M: 0, D: 0, Y: 0 }
    }
]

var result = mingo.aggregate(data, pipeline)

console.log(result)

// Output
// [ { Birthdate: 1995-02-04T00:00:00.000Z, _id: 100 } ]
```

For MongoDB:

```
db.Member.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: Thank you for solution but how can I use this solution to write my query?

Comment: Use the  pipeline query in `mingo.aggregate(data, <pipeline>)` in your own example. Such as: `db.Member.aggregate(<pipeline>) `

Comment: my birthdate field format is like this: "Birthdate" : 983664000000.0 and I want to give above condition for $where. so how can I use this in aggrgation pipeline

Comment: There is is no support for converting types using the aggregation framework as far as I know. You can try iterating your collection using a cursor to see if it is any faster than the `$where` operator. See example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085489/mongodb-convert-integer-to-date